# Procedure inside Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Context: Oracle DB (plsql)

Now I have this procedure, that we call *main*. Inside main I just check some integrity of data.

If everything is fine I call a second procedure (inside main) that I call *import*.

*Import* insert data from a temporary table into a history table (**without commit it**).

Inside *import* I catch any exception.

At the end, *import* return a boolean if success or not, and process return to *main*.

*main* checks that *import* went right, and if so, call a third procedure, *stats*.

Now question:

is it possible that *stats* does not view changes made by *import*? I mean, *stats* is aware about new data that *import* imported into history table?

"Pseudo-Code":

**MAIN PROCEDURE**

```
select count(*) into var1
from table1;

if var1 == 0 then
    storedprocedure_import(result);

    if (result) = true then
          storedprocedure_stats(result);
    end if;
end if;
```

**IMPORT PROCEDURE**

```
insert /*+ append */  into table_history
       select *
       from table_temporary;
```

**STAT PROCEDURE**

```
for tmp_data in (select distinct(data) dta
                     from table_history
                     order by dta)
    loop

      delete from stats_table
      where data = tmp_data.dta;

      insert into stats_table
        select tmp_data.dta, count(*) unique_stb
        from table_history
        where tmp_data.dta = table_history.data
        group by table_history.data;

    end loop;
```

Now I have some doubts about this

```
   insert into stats_table
        select tmp_data.dta, count(*) unique_stb
        from table_history
        where tmp_data.dta = table_history.data
        group by table_history.data;
```

Because I'm not sure that at point where *stats* is called, it is aware about new date inside table_history imported by *import*

Comment: Can you post a code or some pseudo-code? It will be easier to understand your problem.

Comment: @Kacper more than code or pseudo code, gonna try to describe better my procedure

Comment: Stats are collected on tables..If your tables are affected , the stats will impacted .

Comment: If the 3rd procedure is within the same transaction as the first two procedures, then sure, it'll be able to see changes to the data that the other procedures have made. However, why are you passing around whether a procedure failed or succeeded in a parameter? Why not simply let the procedure raise an exception upon failure and then handle that in the calling procedure?

Comment: @Boneist because it's a procedure called by a java tool and I want to have some control on behavior

Comment: Can't Java handle exceptions returned by PL/SQL? I'd be very surprised if it couldn't!

Comment: @Boneist of course it can ahah but are we not just going off topic?

Comment: If you consider good coding practice to be off-topic, sure. It was only an aside, however; my original point stands: if the procedures are within the same transaction (ie. no committing or rolling back takes place in between calls from java to pl/sql) then it should be fine. Or, y'know, you could create a proc in PL/SQL that handles the logic for you?

Comment: Thanks god this is a healthy community

Comment: Because exception handlers often introduce bugs. btw `insert /*+ append */ into table_history` is a direct-path load, which requires a commit before you can do anything with `table_history`.

Comment: First, I wouldn't do a direct path as a normal way of processing, unless the data is very large and I periodically truncate to clear HWM (intermediate or temp tables for example).  Also, I would think if you do use direct path inserts, you should commit afterwards (as part of the import).

Comment: @AntonioCalì why you do not want to use commit?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar because It's a procedure called by a java tool, I want to let the behavior to it

Comment: @WilliamRobertson pls reply, so I can confirm

Comment: Sorry, confirm what?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Reply and not commet, so I can confirm your reply as valid and close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Boneist mentioned, all procedures run in the same transaction (unless you specify otherwise with `pragma automomous_transaction` but let's not go there).

I suspect there is an issue due to the `insert /*+ append */` in your import procedure, as direct path operations have to be committed before you can do anything with the table, including querying it, which your stats procedure attempts to do. It's possible that this is failing and the exception is hidden by your custom error handler.

```
create table demo (c int);

insert /*+ append */ into demo select 1 from dual;

1 row created.

select count(*) from demo;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel
```

As tbone mentioned, `insert /*+ append */` is only useful when batch-loading tens of millions of rows.